# Requisições POST AJAX ASP net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, firefox

Boa tarde, estou com uma pequena dúvida, estou fazendo uma requisição POST com AJAX no ASP net MVC e funciona tudo normal, porem no firefox eu recebo um erro no console
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

entretanto, no chrome nao aparece esse erro.
Aqui esta o código da requisção:

```
    function adicionaCarrinho(quantidade, codigoProduto) {

    var token = $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
    var header = {};
    header['RequestVerificationToken'] = token;

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Produto/AddCarrinho",
        type: 'POST',
        data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token, codigoProduto: codigoProduto, quantidade: quantidade},
        headers: header,
        success: function (data) {
            getCookie();
        },
        error: function (data) {

            console.log('Error' + data);
        }
    });
}
```

e aqui esta o código do controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult AddCarrinho(string codigoProduto, int quantidade)
        {
            HttpCookie cart = Request.Cookies.Get("Cart");
            HttpCookie cartQtd = Request.Cookies.Get("CartQtd");

            if(cart != null)
            {
                _pedidoItensDAO.InsereItem(_pedidoDAO.RetornaPedido(cart.Value), codigoProduto, quantidade);
                cartQtd.Value = (Convert.ToInt32(cartQtd.Value) + quantidade).ToString();
                Response.Cookies.Add(cartQtd);
            }
            else
            {
                var token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                _pedidoDAO.InserePedido(token);
                _pedidoItensDAO.InsereItem(_pedidoDAO.RetornaPedido(token), codigoProduto, quantidade);
                Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("Cart", token));
                Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("CartQtd", quantidade.ToString()));
            }

            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

alguém sabe o motivo do erro no firefox?

Comment: Não estou vendo nada de errado, é mais um chute rsrs. Para teste... tente criar uma classe e dentro dela adicione as propriedades  `codigoProduto` e `quantidade`, pode ser que ele esteja esperando os dados via `QueryString` da forma que está.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com base em algumas pesquisas encontrei que:

> A mensagem de erro é gerada somente pelo FireFox quando a página de
>   renderização está em branco. Por alguma razão, o `.NET` gera um tipo de
>   resposta de `application/xml` quando cria uma página vazia. O Firefox
>   analisa o arquivo como `XML` e não encontra nenhum elemento raiz, envia
>   a mensagem de erro.
>   Fonte: [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46487392/4312593)

No seu caso você está a retornar um `EmptyResult();` que retorna um resultado completamente vazio. Para resolver o problema retorne um objeto `Json` vazio `return Json(string.Empty)`

Comment: Funcionou, exatamente isso, eu tinha procurado alguma coisa mas não havia achado nada, tudo que eu achei era referente a solicitação ajax com algum problema, devo ter procurado errado xD valeu !!